# OpenLiberty - VisualVM

Tags: visualvm, open-liberty

Did anyone tried working with OpenLiberty and VisualVM? I was trying with IBM Liberty 20.0.0.5 and JDK 1.8, i get this exception when using CPU Profiling.

> An exception occurred: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/graalvm/visualvm/lib/jfluid/server/ProfilerRuntimeCPUFullInstr
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.WSThreadLocal.get(WSThreadLocal.java:69)
>       at [internal classes]

Answer (score 1):

Added `-Dorg.osgi.framework.bootdelegation=org.graalvm.*` to Liberty Server its working now.

For more info refer:
https://github.com/oracle/visualvm/issues/209

Comment: The only way this worked is by added this to my bootstrap.properties.  It did not work when I made this a JVM arg when running the jar or adding it to my jvm.options file